# Security Protocol Notation Editor

Tags: protocols

Are there any editors or tools that support the 
[secure protocol notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_protocol_notation)?

Comment: Isn't protocol design an essential part of information security engineering? Isn't communicating the protocol details relevant? With so many specific sites in stackexchange.com, where should this general question be appropriate? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Any TeX editor could do it without breaking a sweat.  There's a [list of them here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_TeX_editors).

Comment: Thanks, maybe my question was misleading but I was looking for tool with  constructs to represent the concepts in protocol notation. TeX is nice but I was looking for something more specific.